# Static SFML 2.2 libraries and Code::Blocks on windows 7

Tags: c++, sfml

I am starting to program games for the first time, but I've been doing general programming for a couple years now. I have Code::Blocks, which I am fairly comfortable with, but now I am struggling with trying to add a game library to my projects.

I decided on SFML 2.2 because it has all of the features I need. I am also planning on writing this in C++ if that affects anything. I read the instructions that SFML has on their site, but I still can't seem to get it to work. I am also under the impression that having the static version of SFML implemented will make the end result program be all one executable file rather than a file that accesses other files. If that is not what this means, please correct me.

I messed with the directories settings like their site mentioned, as well as the linker settings and the compiler settings. I keep getting errors that say something along the lines of...

```
"Undefined reference to 'sf:VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)"
```

...along with many other undefined functions. Any help on implementing game libraries in general would be very helpful as well.

For reference, the tutorial I attempted to follow is at http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/start-cb.php

Answer (score 0):

There's two common pitfalls when using a static library on Windows, one being particular to your linker:

Symbols exported from DLLs have `__declspec(dllexport)` decoration and need to be `__declspec(dllimport)` decorated on use. Software tends to have defines like `SFLM_STATIC` whose presence or absence indicate the right mangling to use.

The GNU linker is sensitive to the order in which libraries and object files are mentioned. Ensure that items that require symbols occur before the items that provide the symbols on the linker command line.